# What effect does the --copyright flag have in JPackage?

Tags: java, java-14, jpackage

What effect does the `--copyright` flag have in **JPackage**?

I have included it in my configuration, but do not see it when I install the application built using it (on Windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--copyright` flag, like other programming languages, adds the copyright sentence to the **details tab in the application properties**, as shown in this image:

[image: Copyright screenshot]